# What is Object.__proto__ and how is it different from Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I think this works;

```
Obj.__proto__ = Object.__proto__
```

in that it passes same objects to left object.
if not, please correct me.

Want to figure out
how 
`Obj.prototype`

differs from `Obj.__proto__`

Answer (score 1):

`Obj.prototype` is what you define to be a prototype of every object constructed with:

```
var obj = new Obj();
```

`Obj.__proto__` is the prototype of the object that is referenced by your `Obj` variable itself, whatever it is (eg. `Obj` may be a function if it's a constructor).

`Object.prototype` is what will be the prototype of every object constructed with `new Object()`.

`Object.__proto__` is the prototype of the `Object` object itself.

But `__proto__` is not standard. See [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) for a standard way to get some object's prototype in ECMAScript 5.1 and ECMAScript 6.